# How to prevent re-render when using sockets on React while using class not hook. How to prevent multiple setState

Tags: reactjs, sockets, setstate, react-google-maps

```
  componentDidMount() {
     this.socket = io(socketUrl());
     this.socket.on('connect', () => {
         this.socket.emit('authentication',
            { token: localStorage.getItem(`Bearer`) })
    });
    
      this.socket.on('track_payload', data => {
         let markers = [...this.state.markers];
         this.setState({markers:data.payload} )
     });
 }
```

How to prevent re-render when using sockets on React while using class not hook. How to prevent multiple setstate.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Class Component, you need to clear your connection to socket using lifecycle method `componentWillUnmount`. Like here:

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  this.socket.close();
}
```

Comment: I disconnected the socket but it does not work at all.